# Run previous command with multiple replacements

Tags: bash, regular-expression, command-history

Many of you probably know that the commands `^foo^bar^` or `!:gs/foo/bar` are useful for running the previous command with replacing the pattern "foo" with the pattern "bar".

But is there a way to replace multiple pattern from the previous command, like for example in `ls *.jpg | grep photo` replacing the words "jpg" and "photo" without too complicated pattern matching like `!:gs/jpg\(.*\)photo/png\1foto`?

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
!!:s/jpg/png/:s/photo/picture/
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not shorter than just retyping your sample command, but you come at it from the other direction and recall only the pieces that you want (here `ls` and `| grep`, then type in the replacements:

```
$ ls *.jpg | grep photo
$ !:0 *.png !:2-3 picture
```

Results in:

> ls *.png | grep picture